# File search pattern: to search all files that does not have a 0 in 11th position of file name in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, system.io.file

What is the syntax for searching all files that don't have a 0 in file name at a specific position
In my case i want to search for all files that doesnt have 0 in 11th position of filename
in place of " * " as shown below

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, fileName + "_*");
```

Comment: Take a look at this other Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022988/searching-for-a-file-on-remote-machine-wmi-c-sharp Maybe WMI which uses SQL-like syntax can do the job

Comment: How does "doesnt have 0 in 11th position" relate to `fileName + "_*"`? Are you saying that `filename` is always nine characters long? Some example filenames would help.

Answer (score 1):

Can't do a "not", but next best thing would be to filter with LINQ.

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, fileName + "_*")
  .Where(x => !Path.GetFileName(x).StartsWith(fileName + "_0"))
  .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try like in following expression:

```
        string path = @"C:\";
        string parameter = "SomeParameter";
        string[] files = Array.FindAll(Directory.GetFiles(path), x => !Path.GetFileName(x).StartsWith(parameter));

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }
```